# Swift Calendar has no member current

Tags: swift, calendar, member

I'm creating a custom calendar in SwiftUI by following a video tutorial. I'm trying to add an extension to get the current month dates, but I am getting a few errors stemming from the "Type 'Calendar' has no member 'current'". I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
extension Date{
    
    func getAllDates()->[Date]{
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!
        
        //getting date
        
        return range.compactMap { day -> Date in
            return calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: .day, to: self)!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems odd. Do you have another type called `Calendar` defined? And also it should read `value: day` and not `value: .day`

Comment: @burnsi, I have the SwiftUI file titled Calendar. Should I try changing the title to calendarView?

Comment: If it is the file itself, it shouldn´t  matter. If you named a class or struct the same name as something that allready exists there will be conflict.

Comment: Yes that is a good way to solve this, another is to refer to the type by adding the module name before the type like Foundation.Calendar or MyApp.Calendar

Comment: You should avoid creating SwiftUI types that have the same name as Foundation (or UIKit) classes. You could fully qualify your reference to Calendar using Foundation.Calendar as Joakim suggests, but better, don't name a class or struct using the name Calendar (or any other system type name.)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same case. After reading the comments to this question I double checked and found the following code in one of my project's files:

```
struct Calendar: View {
...
```

After renaming the struct to CalendarView the error message disappeared.
Thanks @duncan-c for the hint!